# How can I display a file selected from directory listview control with c# window forms?

Tags: c#, listview

My code below displays the listview of a folder, which is selected by the `folderBrowser` control. After displaying the folders and files in a list view, I want to open the file which is clicked. I have written the following code using `LISTVIEW_itemactivation`. The problem is that I can't open the selected file. What am I doing wrong?

```
private void PopulateListView()
{
    listView1.Clear();
    //headers listview

    listView1.Columns.Add("File Name", 150);
    listView1.Columns.Add("Last Accessed", 110);
    listView1.Columns.Add("Size", 100);
    //listView1.ItemActivate += new System.EventHandler(listView1_ItemActivate);


    if (folderBrowser.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {

        string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(folderBrowser.SelectedPath);
        string[] folders = Directory.GetDirectories(folderBrowser.SelectedPath);
        foreach (string file in files)
        {
            long folderSize = 0;
            string fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file);

            FileInfo finfo = new FileInfo(file);
            folderSize += finfo.Length;

            ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(new[] { fileName, File.GetLastAccessTime(file).ToString(), finfo.Length.ToString() });

            images();
            item.ImageIndex = 1;
            listView1.Items.Add(item);

        }

        foreach (string file in folders)
        {
            string fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file);
            ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(new[] { fileName, File.GetLastAccessTime(file).ToString(), file.Length.ToString() });
            images();
            item.ImageIndex = 0;
            listView1.Items.Add(item);
        }
    }
}
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PopulateListView();
    textBox1.Text = folderBrowser.SelectedPath;
}
private void images(){
    try
    {
        imageList1.Images.Add(Bitmap.FromFile("./images/file.gif"));
        imageList1.Images.Add(Bitmap.FromFile("./images/Folder.gif"));
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException) { }

}


private void listView1_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

        ListViewItem item_clicked = listView1.SelectedItems[0];

}
private void radioButton1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    listView1.View = View.LargeIcon;
}

private void radioButton2_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    listView1.View = View.SmallIcon;
}

private void radioButton3_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    listView1.View = View.Details;
}

private void radioButton4_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    listView1.View = View.List;
}

private void radioButton5_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    listView1.View = View.Tile;
}

private void listView1_ItemActivate(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

        try
        {
    string sPath = listView1.SelectedItems.ToString();
    string sFileName = listView1.FocusedItem.Text;

    Process.Start(sPath + "\\" + sFileName);
}
catch(Exception Exc)    {   MessageBox.Show(Exc.ToString());    }    
}
```

Comment: Are you getting an exception?

Comment: no exception i guess im doing something wrong while taking the path and filename

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, based on how you're populating the list, this modified code should work.

```
private void listView1_ItemActivate(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        string sPath = listView1.SelectedItem.SubItems[0].Text;
        Process.Start(sPath);
    }
    catch(Exception Exc)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(Exc.ToString());
    }
}
```

But you'll also need to get rid of this line because you'll ***never*** be able to load the file without knowing it's extension.

```
string fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file);
```

See, when you load a `ListViewItem` like you are it's loading all of the `SubItems` with that array. Further, the array returned by `Directory.GetFiles(folderBrowser.SelectedPath);` returns an array of files with a full path to them, so, if you pick up the first `SubItem` that's going to be the full path to that file and thus issuing `Process.Start` on that file path will cause the shell to open the file in its default program.

Comment: it gives an exception "the system cant find the file specified when i use it like this when i use it like this

Comment: @engineer41: Please see my edit, I think I had a typo in the line that got that path.

Comment: @engineer41: I see the problem. You are removing the extension while loading the list, don't do that.

Comment: string sPath = listView1.SelectedItems.Text; this statement does not take Text defination

Comment: @engineer41: Notice that line changed to `listView1.SelectedItem.SubItems[0].Text`.

Comment: it worked fine when i inserted the values in subitems  and the put them in listview via object....i used foucseditem.text for geting the file open..thanks for ur help micheal:)